# Is it OK with redux sgas to call generator methods directly

Tags: reactjs, generator, redux-saga

Currently I have a root saga that intercepts specific actions. My components dispatch actions via a actioncreator... but do I need these action creators?  Can I just call one of the generator functions from within the component directly instead?

I have only just started using sagas and am not sure if I should still be using action creators.

Comment: Could you post some example code

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of using redux? Bypassing actions means you no longer have time travel debugging or a clear debug path

Comment: I still want to dispatch actions but most of them are now being dispatched within the generator functions themselves anyway using yield put(). so I thought maybe I could just bypass dispatching the initial action that the root saga listen for and just call them somehow directly

Comment: you definitely *could* write your own iterator manager (which is essentially what redux-saga is doing for you). but you lose out on the work they've already done to add effects, and the entire generator/iterator middleware handler that *is* redux-saga. there are use cases for rolling your own generator/iterator middleware, but i'd definitely suggest starting with the [basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and really determine if this is the right way to go

Answer (score 2):

No, you should never call any sagas directly from your application components. The whole point of sagas is that this they abstract side effect management into separate detached layer from the rest of the application. What it means is that your application does not even know that something somewhere is listening for some actions.

You components generate some actions during its workflow, but they never knows if those actions will trigger any other actions. If it happens because saga produces new action – then this is side effect. By keeping side effects separate from the rest of the logic, you achieve high level of abstraction and louse coupling.

So once again, you never want to call sagas function yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

I read one of the benfits of Sagas is they cut down on boilerplate code... but now I have to alter my root saga everytime I want to take a new action and then create  a worker for it. I can see why I should use sagas but if anything - as far as boilerplate code goes - my code is increasing not decreasing. That is why I was hoping I could just trigger a generator function manually and not bother with the action creators and just use put() in my generators to dispatch actions.